# creating jQuery function to reduce code

Tags: jquery

currently i have separate functions for hover and click events but list of icons is growing and i want to make universal function that can work with all the icons, but I'm not sure where to start at. btw I'm aware that I'm using same images for backhoe and excavator src.

```
var excavator = false;
var backhoe = false;
var paver = false;
var compactor = false;
var motorgrator = false;


$("#excavator").mouseleave(function () {
    if(!excavator)
        $(this).attr("src", "img/default_excavator.png");
});
$("#excavator").mouseenter(
  function () {
      if(!excavator)
        $(this).attr("src", "img/hover_excavator.png");
});
$("#excavator").click(
  function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "img/active_excavator.png");
    $("#equipmentList").load('partials/excavator.php');
    excavator = true;
    backhoe = false;
    $("#backhoe").attr("src", "img/default_excavator.png");
});

/******************** end of excavator ********************/

$("#backhoe").mouseleave(function () {
    if(!backhoe)
        $(this).attr("src", "img/default_excavator.png");
});
$("#backhoe").mouseenter(
  function () {
      if(!backhoe)
        $(this).attr("src", "img/hover_excavator.png");
});
$("#backhoe").click(
  function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "img/active_excavator.png");
    $("#equipmentList").load('partials/backhoe.php');
    backhoe = true;
    excavator = false;
    $("#excavator").attr("src", "img/default_excavator.png");
});

$('#top').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
 });
```

below is the part from html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3>Equipments</h3>
                <div id="equipmentSelection" class="block-inline" style="margin-bottom: 1%">
                    <img id="excavator" src="img/default_excavator.png" alt=""/>
                    <img id="backhoe" src="img/default_excavator.png" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div id="equipmentList" class="panel-body">
                    <h4>Select above to browse our equipments</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: don't really understand logic... why do you have to click on image before you can toggle the source for that image in hover?

Comment: i have three image for each button, one to indicate hovering, and one default state, and third to indicate if button is clicked, because upon click it will show data related to that button

Comment: easy enough to add a class to one that's clicked and change it's style with that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your function to the generic container class, and check inside your function which is the id of the current element:

```
$(".container .row-fluid .col-lg-12 img").mouseleave(function () {
    if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'excavator' )
    {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

    if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'backhoe' )
    {
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE
    }
});
```

Comment: on your answer first line can i replace that with just $("#equipmentSelection").mouseleve ? since all the icons/buttons are inside that div with equipmentSelection id.

Comment: yes you can, but in that case you will not know which IMG was being hovered

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio not true... in any jQuery event `this` is element acted on so can do same with `mouseenter`

Comment: @charlietfl, I've never said he cannot do the same with mouseenter. I said if he binds the function to a different element he won't be able to check WHICH IMG was being mousehovered.